# Импорт данных из Excel в SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

Хочу импортировать данные в таблицу из файла Excel версии 2007 или выше в SQL Server.  Ниже фрагмент используемого кода:

```
    sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
    RECONFIGURE;
    GO
    sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
    RECONFIGURE;
    GO

    SELECT * INTO Data_dq
    FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Data Source=C:\Users\musayevk\Desktop\aaa.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Data$];
```

Текст полученной ошибки:

```
Error Log
Msg 7438, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server.
```

Comment: У вас все уже написано в ошибке, ищите 32 машину или поставьте 64 битный драйвер.

Comment: В Смысле ищите я не понял. Если речь идет о этат файле (АксессДатабасеЕнгине.exe) я уже попробовал ничего не изменился. У меня виндовс 64 битная

Answer (score 2):

Скачайте 64 битный драйвер [отсюда](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

После произвидите установку в сайлент моде, через командную строку:

```
"C:\Users\%User%\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" /passive
```

%User% - замените на свое имя пользователя.

флаг `/passive` даст установить драйвер рядом с драйвером на 32 бита.

Comment: Я эту уже попробовал но не получился. Тот же ошибка

Comment: Точные не скачивается /passive

Comment: @KamranMusayev какую ошибку? Можно еще попробовать удалить офис который у вас уже есть и поставить 64 битный.

Comment: хорошо кроме этого все попробовал. спасибо за совет. напишу если после установки . ошибка  когда делаю /passive ничего не показывает

Comment: Скачал 64 быть все равно не работает. Сейчас даёт такой ошибка Msg 7438, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server.